# C# moving Mouse interrupst Dispatcher Timer

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, timer

I am currently working on an programm, where I want to automaticly move an ellipse with a Dispatcher Timer. It works fine, as long as my mouse stands still. However, as soon as I start moving my mouse, the ellipse moves very slow, or even stops moving completly. When is stop moving it, the programm runs properly again. The ellipse is a Child of a Canvas, an there is no other UI element in the background other than this canvas. I also did not add any events to the canvas.
My goal is, to move the mouse over the application, without having an impact on the animation.
Does someone have any suggestions for fixing this problem?
Thank you in advance!
Azuro

Here is all the code from a minimal reproducible example:
Xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Canvas.SetLeft(Ball, 0);
        Canvas.SetTop(Ball, 225);

        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(4.16666666);
        timer.Tick += Move;

        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((MapCanvas.ActualWidth - Ball.Width) > Canvas.GetLeft(Ball))
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(Ball, Canvas.GetLeft(Ball) + 2);
        }
    }
}
```

And here the xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="BallSpielExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BallSpielExample"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="MapCanvas" Background="NavajoWhite" Width="auto" Height="auto">
        <Ellipse Name="Ball" Width="30" Height="30" Fill="SaddleBrown"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You better create an [mcve] and include that in your question so we won't have to guess which problems your imaginary code has.

Comment: Ok, thanks, im working on it.

Comment: `DispatcherTimer` is executed on the same thread as other `Dispatcher` operations. Check if setting a different `DispatcherPriority` (param of one of the constructors of `DispatcherTimer`) will help. If it doesn't, consider using `System.Timers.Timer` instead - it runs on a separate thread (you'll have to use `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` to update GUI from its `Elapsed` event).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority?view=net-5.0

Comment: i think you're not taking full use of animation in wpf. try doubleanimation

Comment: It is absolutely ok to use a DispatcherTimer instead of CompositionTarget.Rendering or some animation. You just have to make sure the timing interval is large enough, e.g. 30-50 milliseconds, and you determine the elapsed time since the last Tick handler invocation in a similar way as shown in the accepted answer. Optionally by DateTime.Now instead of a Stopwatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is, that the DispatcherTime is not steady enough, so not useful for animations. The second problem is that you should use the (delta)time to calculate the movement. If you use WPF animations, you're losing control on their position etc. (boundschecking etc)

I would use the [`CompositionTarget.Rendering`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering?view=net-5.0) event for that. This way you're moving the ball on the renderthread.

Use a stopwatch to time the movement, because you want it to move it at the same speed on different devices.

I've made a little example to show how it works:

***MainWindow.xaml***

```
<Window x:Class="BouncingBall.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BouncingBall"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Canvas x:Name="MapCanvas">
        <Ellipse Name="Ball" Width="30" Height="30" Fill="SaddleBrown"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

---

***MainWindow.xaml.cs***

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private double _ballPositionX = 100;
    private double _ballPositionY = 100;
    private double _ballSpeedX = 225; // pixels per second
    private double _ballSpeedY = 150; // pixels per second

    private TimeSpan _previousTime;

    private readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _previousTime = _stopwatch.Elapsed;

        // set the (initial) position
        UpdateBall(0);

        // Attach the Update method on the WPF renderTarget <----
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += Update;
    }

    private void Update(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // check delta time
        var currentTime = _stopwatch.Elapsed;
        var delta = (currentTime - _previousTime).TotalSeconds;
        _previousTime = currentTime;

        UpdateBall(delta);
        // if you want to animate multiple shapes, Call something like UpdateBall
    }

    private void UpdateBall(double delta)
    {
        // ensure that the ball moves by using the deltatime.
        _ballPositionX += _ballSpeedX * delta;
        _ballPositionY += _ballSpeedY * delta;

        // check bounds X
        if (_ballPositionX < 0)
        {
            _ballSpeedX = -_ballSpeedX;
            _ballPositionX = 0;
        }
        else if (_ballPositionX > MapCanvas.ActualWidth - Ball.ActualWidth)
        {
            _ballSpeedX = -_ballSpeedX;
            _ballPositionX = MapCanvas.ActualWidth - Ball.ActualWidth;
        }

        // check bounds Y
        if (_ballPositionY < 0)
        {
            _ballSpeedY = -_ballSpeedY;
            _ballPositionY = 0;
        }
        else if (_ballPositionY > MapCanvas.ActualHeight - Ball.ActualHeight)
        {
            _ballSpeedY = -_ballSpeedY;
            _ballPositionY = MapCanvas.ActualHeight - Ball.ActualHeight;
        }

        // update the position
        Canvas.SetLeft(Ball, _ballPositionX);
        Canvas.SetTop(Ball, _ballPositionY);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for anserwing with this quality. I am aware of the deltatime problem. But I do not understand what causes the "Update" method to run frequently? And how often does it run?

Comment: @Azuro The update method is attached to the [CompositionTarget.Rendering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering?view=net-5.0) eventhandler _(see the last codeline of the MainWindow constructor)_. Which is triggered aprox 60 fps  (it's the WPF renderthread).

Comment: ok, thank you very much. Is there any way to increase or decrease die amount of triggers per second?

Comment: No, why would you want that? Calculating faster points without able to draw them is useless. If you want more fps, you shouldn't use WPF

Comment: oh ok, i did not know that WPF maxes out at 60 FPS. What should i use instead?

Comment: Whats the problem with max 60 fps (for a bouncing ball) ;-)

Comment: Sure, i would not need more for that. But the actual goal is to programm a tower defence game without using a game engine. The bouncing ball ist just a minimal problem example of moving an enemy across the map :)

Comment: WPF is not optimized to render many (moving) sprites. The next step is something like direct-x. But much harder.

Answer (score 1):

Use the animation below

```
private void Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((MapCanvas.ActualWidth - Ball.Width) >= Canvas.GetLeft(Ball))
    {
        MoveAnim(Ball, .00001, Canvas.GetLeft(Ball), Canvas.GetLeft(Ball) + 2);
    }
}
public static void MoveAnim(UIElement element, double duration, double from, double to)
{
    string property = "(Canvas.Left)";
    Storyboard myStoryboard = new Storyboard();
    myStoryboard.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd;
    DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();

    animation.From = from;
    animation.To = to;
    animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration);
    animation.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd;
    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, element);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(property));
    myStoryboard.Children.Add(animation);
    myStoryboard.Begin();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(4.16666666);
```

makes not much sense. A DispatcherTimer is neither supposed to run at 200 Hz nor is it supposed to run precisely to a fraction of a millisecond. The Ellipse should be moved by a DoubleAnimation or a PointAnimation.

The DoubleAnimation in the following example animates the `Canvas.Left` property of the Ellipse by 2 units every 5 milliseconds. Since the animation runs forever, you could as well use other values for the `By` and `Duration` properties, but keep their ratio, e.g. `By = 20` and `Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50)`.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Canvas.SetLeft(Ball, 0);
    Canvas.SetTop(Ball, 225);

    var animation = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        By = 2,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5),
        IsCumulative = true,
        RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
    };

    Ball.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, animation);
}
```