# visual studio debugging only working when mouse not moving over blank area - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, lag

**problem**

when running an application through debug or release on visual studio, the application only works when moving my mouse around buttons, [example](https://giant.gfycat.com/JollyImpressiveEel.mp4). When doing ctrl+f5, or just running the .exe file outright, it functions perfectly, [example](https://giant.gfycat.com/ShortDiligentEmu.mp4).

**what I've tried**

I've run multiple different apps, some as simple as just counting up a variable and setting that variable to a label, I've tried visual studio 2022, and 2019, uninstalled both, then tried 2022 again. I've tried different versions of .NET from 4.6.1 framework to the latest version. I've tried unticking and ticking lots of stuff in **tools>options>debugging>general**. None of it has remedied the issue. When the same application is run on school computers, this issue is not present, and everything functions perfectly, debugging or not.

is there something I'm missing here?

Edit: examples of a much simpler application:

[debugging](https://giant.gfycat.com/UnrulyLankyGlassfrog.mp4)

[non-debugging](https://giant.gfycat.com/ElectricSeparateAtlanticsharpnosepuffer.mp4)

Comment: This might answer your question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68265474/c-sharp-moving-mouse-interrupst-dispatcher-timer

Comment: while that's interesting to see why the mouse delays the program, that doesn't answer why debug mode is crippling the performance of the app.

Comment: Your timer has literally zero delay, trying to run on the Dispatcher.  That's never going to not be affected by other things in the UI.  The Debugger just makes this clearer by putting a bigger load on everyting

Comment: I am aware of the effects of a 0 delay dispatch timer, and how everything gets queued up and therefor you get delays, but the problem is that the debug mode is significantly slower on my computer than on every other computer I've been on, leading to it being impossible to run any program in debug mode as a result of the slow timings. The problem isn't hardware, as my computer has a faster GPU and CPU than any other that I've been on. My laptop can run debug mode faster...

Comment: Sounds then like this is either your Visual Studio setup or your computer setup.     I suppose my next step - if this were me - would be to fire up the visual diagnostics window and see where your application is spending the bulk of its time while this lag is happening.   It might at least give you some clue as to what to investigate next.